# ComboBox SelectionChanged event fires late

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

In my WPF application, I have a ComboBox that I am using to select an ItemFilter for an AutoCompletebox. Here is the code:

XAML

```
<ComboBox 
     Name="SearchFilter" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
     MinWidth="75" Margin="0,3,0,3" 
     SelectionChanged="SearchFilter_SelectionChanged">
          <ComboBoxItem>Full-Time</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>Part-Time</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>Retired</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>Stockholder</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>Terminated</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
private void SearchFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchFilter.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (SearchFilter.Text == "Full-Time")
            {
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Full;
            }
            else if (SearchFilter.Text == "Part-Time")
            {
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Part;
            }
            else if (SearchFilter.Text == "Retired")
            {
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Ret;
            }
            else if (SearchFilter.Text == "Stockholder")
            {
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Stock;
            }
            else if (SearchFilter.Text == "Terminated")
            {
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Term;
            }
            else
            {
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter;
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the filter is being applied after I changed the selection is changed. For example, I set the ComboBox to "Full-Time", the list filter is not being applied. Then I set the ComboBox to "Part-Time, the Full-Time filter is being applied. Then I set the ComboBox to "Retired", the Part Time filter is being applied. Etc, etc... I have used a ComboBox for similar things before and it usually works based on what is currently in the box, not what was in the box. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's in `e.AddedItems` in that SelectionChanged handler? `SearchFilter.SelectedItem` and `SearchFilter.SelectedValue` should have been updated as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Text` is just about the only property of `SearchFilter` that won't have been updated in your SelectionChanged handler (don't ask me why not).

`SelectedItem` will be good, `SelectedValue` will be good (in your case, both will be the selected `ComboBoxItem` -- not a great way to use WPF, but I'm not your priest), and `SelectedIndex`.

We'll make one small change to the XAML (see below) so we can get the selected string from `SelectedValue`.

```
private void SearchFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  Not sure there's any reason for this null check. 
    if (SearchFilter.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        var filter = SearchFilter.SelectedValue as String;

        switch (filter)
        {
            case "Full-Time":
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Full;
                break;
            case "Part-Time":
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Part;
                break;
            case "Retired":
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Ret;
                break;
            case "Stockholder":
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Stock;
                break;
            case "Terminated":
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter_Term;
                break;
            default:
                EmployeeAutoBox.ItemFilter = PersonFilter;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML: The only change aside from indenting is adding the `SelectedValuePath="Content"` attribute. What that does is, when the selection changes (and before the event is raised), the ComboBox will now look at the object in `SelectedItem`, whatever it may be, and look for a property on it named "Content". If it finds that, it'll use the value of the `SelectedItem`'s `Content` property for `SelectedValue`. The content you're giving these is the strings: "Part-Time", etc. So then

```
<ComboBox 
    Name="SearchFilter" 
    SelectedValuePath="Content"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    MinWidth="75" 
    Margin="0,3,0,3" 
    SelectionChanged="SearchFilter_SelectionChanged"
    >
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="Full-Time">Full-Time</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Part-Time</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Retired</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Stockholder</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Terminated</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Wow, quick response. Your comment above, reminded me to use SelectedItem instead. I'm fairly new to WPF and not super familiar with MVVM. Why do you say that its not a great way to use WPF? I'm always open to better ways to do things, even if its just a concept or something I can look up.

Comment: @Pants For example, a more "correct" way would be to populate the ComboBox by binding its ItemsSource to a collection property of your viewmodel, then `SelectedItem` would be an item from the collection. In that case, you could use `SelectedValuePath="WhateverProperty"` as I did in my update, and then you could bind `SelectedValue` to another viewmodel property. Turning your whole project into an MVVM thing may be prohibitive at this point; I don't want to be too ranty about it.

Comment: Probably a tad prohibitive, as its a work project and they wanted something quick and dirty that works, but no reason not to improve the way I do things moving forward and then maybe tidying up at the end if time permits. I'll give some thought to what you said. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, work isn't blue sky time. Do take a look at my updated answer though, if you didn't already. It's a bit more simplified, and dips a toe in the WPF "right way".