# ComboBox SelectionChanged Event shows previous Items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 ComboBoxes. And the Second ComboBox will Enabled when i Choose/Change the Item in the first ComboBox. But the Second ComboBox always shows me the previous Items.

For example:
I change Item in ComboBox 1. And ComboBox2 don't show me any items.
I change Item in ComboBox 1 again. Now ComboBox2 shows me the items which should shown by first change.

Here is my Code:

```
private void categoryComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    subCategoryComboBox.Items.Clear();
    subCategoryComboBox.IsEnabled = true;

    string SelectedCategoryID = ConvertBackCategory(categoryComboBox.Text);
    connection = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string);
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM auftrags_typ_childcategory WHERE category = @CategoryID";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", SelectedCategoryID);
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        subCategoryComboBox.Items.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

How I can fix this? / Why it shows me not the current items?

Answer (score 2):

[The `Text` property of the WPF ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) is not updated until after the `SelectionChanged` event is raised. Don't ask me why, but it isn't. They seem to have intended the `Text` property only to be used for combo boxes with editable text.

*Every other* relevant property of the `ComboBox` is updated *before* `SelectionChanged` is raised.

`SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, and `SelectedIndex` will all be correct and current in your `SelectionChanged` handler. [I answered this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504980/combobox-selectionchanged-event-fires-late/43505181#43505181); you should be able to adapt that answer to your needs without too much trouble, but let me know if you hit a snag.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't saw that question in Google so I though this type of fail doesn't exists here..